# How DB ( e.g. oracle) make index for string fields?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

For example I've a 2 fields table: ID | NAME
Index on NAME is created. How RDBMS (e.g. oracle) stored/manage it? In B-Tree? lexicographic order ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/indexes-and-index-organized-tables.html#GUID-DE7A95BC-6E4A-47EA-9FC5-B85B54F8CF41

Comment: Yes, as the link above says, the default is B-tree heap-organized index in ascending order, binary collation (ordered by ASCII/unicode values). See here for more on collation. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG295